# How did Grace know about Carl's location?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-dark-fate

In *Terminator: Dark Fate*, when Grace analyses Sarah's phone she finds that they came from Laredo, Texas. She then points out that her Commander had just tattooed these coordinates on her body (sounds a bit drastic, Grace being enhanced would surely be able to remember lots of details, thankfully he didn't do the full map).

But, how could her Commander possibly know about Carl (or at least of this location) and what was the significance of the coordinates? Carl came from a deleted time line. Was this to be explored in future sequels?

Answer (score 2):

This is a straightforward (as straightforward as these things get) case of a predestination paradox. It's the same type as seen in the original *The Terminator*.

Grace's Commander was part of those events. Without Carl's help, Grace and Sarah Connor would have undoubtedly failed to defeat the Rev-9, and the Rev-9 would have succeeded in killing Dani and preventing the future resistance. But,

> future Dani

knew to tattoo Carl's location onto Grace because

> present Dani

was there when the group used those same tattooed coordinates to meet Carl, and knew that Carl was required defeat the Rev-9 and save

> present Dani's

life.

TLDR; the resistance in the future was only able to send Grace back into time because Grace had already travelled back in time and ensured the Resistance's existence.